# Javascript visibility function with transition

Tags: javascript, html, css

I made a JavaScript on-click function for a div to hide or show it using visibility. How can I add a transition to this function so my div won't appear too sudden?

```
    function about()
{
    var elem = document.getElementById('about');
    elem.style.visibility = "visible";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*solution 1 (CSS3 + JS):*

css:

```
#about{ transition:all ease 2s; opacity:0;}
```

and js:

```
function about()
{
    document.getElementById('about').style.opacity = 1;
}
```

*Solution 2 (JS only):*

```
function about()
{
(function reveal(val){
    document.getElementById('about').style.opacity = val;
    if(val<1) setTimeout(reveal,1,val+0.001);
})(0);
}
```

Note: youre just able to toggle visibility (on/off). The opacity defines how much you can "look trough", it goes from 0 (nothing visible) to 1 (all visible)...

Comment: The first solution works, but when I reload the page, the div is there and dimming away, then if i click on my button, it shows like it should. Where is the problem?